# Android mk - get substring

Tags: android, makefile

### $(ORIGINAL) = a.b_c=200 d.e_f=300

I want to get a.b_c 's value.(200)

I try like below.

```
$(filter a.b_c=%, $(ORIGINAL))
```

then, I received "**a.b_c=200**"

now I want to get value 200.

Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`subst`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions):

```
TERM:= $(filter a.b_c=%, $(ORIGINAL))
N := $(subst a.b_c=,,$(TERM))
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function) to create normal make variables, then simply reference those variables.  For example:

```
ORIGINAL = a.b_c=200 d.e_f=300

$(foreach n,$(ORIGINAL),$(eval $(n)))
all:
    @echo The value is $(a.b_c)
```

Running this produces the following output:

```
$ gmake
The value is 200
```